# I want to get value by session id but it is null value . I use to login from this table(email and password)

Tags: laravel, session

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTkAm.png)

**Here is the code and put session-id**

```
public function login(Request $request)
{

    $email=$request->email;
    $password=$request->password;
    $students=Student::where('email','=',$email)
    ->where('password','=',$password)
    ->first();

    if($students)
    {
        Session::put('email',$request->email);
        Session::put('id',$request->id);
        //dd($students);
        return redirect()->route('student.dashboard');

    }
    else
    {
        Session()->flash('success','Invalid Email & and password');
        return redirect()->route('index');
    }

}
```

**and when I get the session id then it returns me null**

```
public function studentview() 
{
      $id=session()->get('id');
      dd($id);
     //return view('student.studentview');
}
```

Actually I want the value of the row which row i used to login.
and pass the student view pages. please help me.

Comment: check the value of $request->id

Comment: I think the value of $request->id is null..and it is assigned to the session variable.

Comment: put a dd(Session::get('id')) after setting session variable

Comment: How can I slive this..?  you seed the database.. table.. which i provided

Comment: instead of `dd($students)` put a `dd($request->id)` and check the value of id which is assigning.

Comment: oky just one minute than i show it

Comment: public function studentview(Request $request) {

    $id=session()->get('id');
    dd($request->id);

  
         //return view('student.studentview');
 } i use it but it is null . as previous value :(

Comment: check the answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code..You are assigning `$request->id` to session variable..Actual value needed is `$students->id`.

put `use Session;` at the top of your controller.

```
public function login(Request $request){

$email=$request->email;
$password=$request->password;
$students=Student::where('email','=',$email)
->where('password','=',$password)
->first();

if($students){
    Session::put('email',$students->email);
    Session::put('id',$students->id);
    Session::save();
    //dd($students);
    return redirect()->route('student.dashboard');

}



else{
    Session()->flash('success','Invalid Email & and password');
    return redirect()->route('index');
}

}

public function studentview() 
{
  if(Session::has('id'))
  {
  $id=Session::get('id');
  dd($id);
  }
 //return view('student.studentview');
 }
```

Comment: please help any think change my another function     public function studentview() 
{
      $id=session()->get('id');
      dd($id);
     //return view('student.studentview');
}

Comment: try but it gets null value :( it is very sad for me sir :( from last night I try to solve it but I can not :(

Comment: Can you just try again.